# Split array between 2 symbols

Tags: python, arrays, django, string, split

I have a really long array from where I want to get some data, but the data I'm interested in is between this signs `<` and `>`

I have many of them.

If I wanted them all in a single array, how could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> test_str = "<1>dadad<2>gfdgf<3>"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?=<).*?(?<=>)', test_str)
['<1>', '<2>', '<3>']
```

Note that you have to use lazy match, otherwise output will be `['<1>dadad<2>gfdgf<3>']`